# How to get the dashboard address from the Dask scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When starting a dask distributed local cluster, you can set a random port or address for the `dashboard_address`.

If you later get the `scheduler` object. Is there a way to extract the address of the dashboard.

I have this:

```
cluster = dask.distributed.LocalCluster(scheduler_port=0,
                                        dashboard_address='localhost:0')
scheduler = dask.distributed.Client(cluster, set_as_default=False)
scheduler_info = scheduler.scheduler_info()
logger.info('Scheduler: %s', scheduler_info['address'])
logger.info('Status Port: %s', scheduler_info['services']['dashboard'])
```

But that only gets the port of the dashboard, not the IP of the dashboard. If I were to put the dashboard address on a separate IP other than the scheduler, seems like it would be difficult to know what IP it was bound to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you defined a `dashboard_address` you can get that info with the following:

```py
In [1]: from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client

In [2]: cluster = LocalCluster(dashboard_address='172.22.1.26:8782')

In [3]: cluster.scheduler.services['dashboard'].server.address
Out[3]: '172.22.1.26'

In [4]: cluster.scheduler.services['dashboard'].server.port
Out[4]: 8782
```

Note: When a `dashboard_address` is not defined, the dashboard will be at the scheduler address -- often `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Can you get it from the scheduler object instead?

Answer (score 4):

```py
# if you have the cluster object
cluster.dashboard_link

# or if you have a client
client.dashboard_link
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.